# How can I find the location of a Javascript Syntax error when using eval?

Tags: javascript

I have a long string that I am calling eval on. It's resulting in a syntax error. I'm trying to figure out where in the eval string the syntax error is. The page is executing in IE 9.

This code string is the result of a large process and is very legacy code. The architecture can't change now as that is out of the scope of the defect I'm working on. It's not a great system and certainly not a system I would write, but it is what it is.

Comment: are you able to debug the string as a script? Is there a ***very*** good reason to use `eval` (I only know of 2)?

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the `eval` with `console.log`, run the logged string through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and spot the syntax error.

As in:

`eval( "very huge string" )`

-->

`console.log( "very huge string" )`

Answer (score 0):

By refactoring so you don't need to use eval, there is almost always a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use eval. Put your code out of `eval()` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Tell your app to spit out your string before eval-ing and running into the syntax error. You can now either

- Put that into another file and tell the browser to run that. (error messages are usually better this way)
- Copy and paste the code into [JSHint](http://jshint.com) and ask it to find the syntax error for you.